# Twilio sms sender api in python does not work

Tags: python, sms, twilio

My code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Find these values at https://twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "your_auth_token"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

client.api.account.messages.create(
    to="+#############",
    from_="+###########",
    body="Hello there!")
```

The error which I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Keshavarz\Desktop\twilio1.py", line 14, in <module>
    body='Hello there!'
  File "C:\Users\Keshavarz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\api\v2010\account\message\__init__.py", line 92, in create
    data=data,
  File "C:\Users\Keshavarz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\twilio\base\version.py", line 209, in create
    raise self.exception(method, uri, response, 'Unable to create record')
twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: 
[31m[49mHTTP Error[0m [37m[49mYour request was:[0m

[36m[49mPOST /Accounts/AC2b7b52ba2fc52a5eebf2c060257f7a7c/Messages.json[0m

[37m[49mTwilio returned the following information:[0m

[34m[49mUnable to create record[0m

[37m[49mMore information may be available here:[0m

[34m[49mhttps://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/451[0m
```

I meet all things to make SID  and Authentication token [based on this link](https://programmingliftoff.com/send-text-messages-from-python-100-free/) but I could not send any SMS to my cell phone #

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here to learn how to improve your questions (formatting, proofreading, providing code etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I suggest you remove your cell phone number from your post.

Comment: POST Response: 400 {"code": 21211, "message": "The 'To' number 8511153398 is not a valid phone number.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211", "status": 400} on fail from twilio return json. that's important to manage.

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is a URL in that response that should help explain what's going on. Sadly it seems to have been garbled somewhat in the log.

What I'd suggest is that you catch the error and try to print it another way. Try this and see what the result is:

```
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
try:
    client.api.account.messages.create(
        to="+#############",
        from_="+###########",
        body="Hello there!")
except TwilioRestException as ex:
    print(ex)
```

Comment: On exception, POST Response: 400 {"code": 21211, "message": "The 'To' number 8511153398 is not a valid phone number.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21211", "status": 400}

unable to get, in twilio this most important to get json of 400

Comment: @TejasTank It looks like the number you tried to send to is not an international formatted number. I'm guessing you're trying to send to an Indian number? If that is the case, then set the `To` number to `+918511153398` (including the international code +91).